# php function not returning results to ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web

I went through solutions provided to similar questions in stackoverflow and other as well. (Seems like its not only me with this problem ).  so i finally am posting the question with a hope to find some solution.

I am sending 2 numbers to php function via ajax call and expect to get sum from function. I think i am right not sure though, that half of the ajax is right and half not i.e. i can send values to php function(i think) but i cant get sum instead in success message i get "html data of the page" :D

Can you please point my mistake and viable solution. Thank you lovely people :)

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(event){

        var num1 = Number($('#num1').val());
        var num2 = Number($('#num2').val());
        var summ = num1+num2;
        //var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
        console.log(" nums are " + summ); //totally works
        var myNums = "num1= " + num1 + " & num2=" + num2; 
        alert(myNums);       //totally works
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'arrayTest.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {num1 : num1,
                    num2 : num2 },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(" <br>success yr data is " + myNums);
                var results = data;
                alert(data); // i get html of the entire page containing form
                return false;
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log(" sorry error " + error); // get this when i add header in php 
            }
        });
    });

});
```

html :

```
<form id ="myForm" method="post" action="">  

  number1: <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1">
  <br><br>
  number2: <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2">
  <br><br>
   <br><br>
  <input type="submit" id ="submit" name="submit" value="add">  
</form>
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
    $result= $num1 + $num2;
    //echo "num1 is ".$num1;// **i didnt see any echo** 

    echo " your result ". $result; // **i didnt see any echo** 
    return ($result);
}
```

PS: html and ajax is in same page, php function in another; I see message

> ```
>   XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/phpTest/arrayTest.php"."
> ```

in console (i dont have idea what it means !!)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, your check for `$_POST['submit']` is the culprit here. The POST data you send along with your request doesn't have a key called `'submit'` in it, so the PHP code never executes like you expect.

Comment: I strongly suggest you utilize the browser's Dev Tools.  You can examine exactly what gets sent and received from an AJAX query - it takes a lot of the guesswork out.

Comment: @Connor You're not wrong, post that as an answer.

Comment: @Connor Thank you for your suggestion. Actually if i am not wrong you meant the i should have used $_POST['add'] or something? If yes, sorry to tell that it had not helped me actually ....

Answer (score 1):

Your form define num1, num2 and add but you are using submit which is not define.

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){

  $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
  $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
  $result= $num1 + $num2;
  //echo "num1 is ".$num1;// **i didnt see any echo** 

   echo " your result ". $result; // **i didnt see any echo** 
   return ($result);
}
```

**TIPS:** Always turn on error reporting and development Environment and use **print_r()** to inspect variable

Comment: Thank you friend. Turns out that i tried your solution beforehand i posted here ..I thought it could be one of reason so I had been trying to change 'POST' to 'add' and vice-versa.

Comment: UPDATE: use print_r($_POST) and notice sudmit/add was sent with the form

Comment: ..i used it in php page and no error found (unless i used it before the function/if(isset...))

Comment: sorry for the typo i meant add/submit is'n part of the post data. Perhaps you should consider adding it with JavaScript or replace   **isset($_POST['add'])** with **isset($_POST)**

Comment: Princewell Thanks a lott my friend -Your solution is perfect ..I now got print_r($num1+$num2) in php file as alert ...but still this is not flashing in ajax "data/result"

Answer (score 0):

If your code works just disable XMLHttpRequests from chrome console.

- open the console -> click the vertical "..." in the top right -> go to settings, and uncheck "Log XMLHttpRequests" under the "Console" header.